# Padding in FXML the content of a TabPane, but not the tab bar

Tags: javafx, tabs, fxml

I am looking for an elegant way of setting a padding to a TabPane, but without padding the tab bar:

```
<TabPane>
    <padding>
        <Insets top="10" bottom="10" right="10" left="10" />
    </padding>
    <Tab text="red">
        <Rectangle fill="RED" width="200" height="200" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="blue">
        <Rectangle fill="BLUE" width="200" height="200" />
    </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

gives:
[image: (unwanted) global padding]

however,

```
<TabPane>
    <Tab text="red">
        <VBox>
            <padding>
                <Insets top="10" bottom="10" right="10" left="10" />
            </padding>
            <Rectangle fill="RED" width="200" height="200" />
        </VBox>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="blue">
        <VBox>
            <padding>
                <Insets top="10" bottom="10" right="10" left="10" />
            </padding>
            <Rectangle fill="BLUE" width="200" height="200" />
        </VBox>
    </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

gives:
[image: Correct padding]

which is exactly what i want, however I want to simplify the FXML structure, mainly by refactoring the `<padding>` element so it's declared in one place (shorter and non-repeating code) and not in every tab of the pane.

So is there any way to achieve this? Or am I stuck with my repeated `<padding>` elements? I'd prefer an FXML solution, but if no way exists a Java one is OK.

Comment: No; padding is applied to `Regions` and without first adding a `Region` (or container) to each tab, there is nothing to apply the padding to.

Comment: If you got what you need for the second part of your question, go with it. `I want to simplify the FXML structure, mainly by refactoring the  <padding> element so it's declared in one place (shorter and non-repeating code) and not in every tab of the pane.` <- I am not sure if the benefit of trying to do this is worth it¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I updated the answer to use the CSS selectors from fabian's comment down below.

You can set padding for most JavaFX scene graph objects in a separate css file. You will need to link the css file to your FXML file which I will show below. The css file and the FXML file will need to be in the same directory, otherwise you will have to edit the `value="..."` tag.

*style.css*

```
.tab-pane > .tab-content-area > * {
    -fx-padding: 10 10 10 10;
}
```

This sets padding to all the `VBox`es that happen to be under a `Tab` somewhere (no matter how deep in the hierarchy)

*main.fxml*

```
<TabPane>
    <Tab text="red">
        <VBox> 
            <Rectangle fill="RED" width="200" height="200" />
        </VBox>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="blue">
        <VBox>
            <Rectangle fill="BLUE" width="200" height="200" />
        </VBox>
    </Tab>

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@style.css" />
    </stylesheets>
</TabPane>
```

Comment: You're on the right track but I'd not assume all `Tab` contents are `VBox`es and that there are no `VBox`es that are descendants of the content vboxes. `.tab-pane > .tab-content-area>* { ... }`

Comment: Thanks Blake, thanks fabian, using `.tab-content-area > * {
 -fx-padding: 10 10 10 10;
}` works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In a word: no.

Each `Tab` of the `TabPane` accepts a `Node` for it's `contentProperty`. The content itself is not a `Region` and therefore cannot have `Insets` or padding applied to it. The `TabPane` itself does not contain a method that allows you to style the content of all the child `Tabs` at once.

You must first add a container of some sort to the `Tab` in order to apply padding. So the second method in your question **is** the simplest way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

**A Workaround**

While this cannot be done with FXML, you could use a Java loop to add the same padding to all of your `Tab` objects after loading the scene:

```
Insets insets = new Insets(10);
for (Tab tab : tabPane.getTabs()) {
    ((VBox) tab.getContent()).setPadding(insets);
}
```

This assumes, of course, that you use a `VBox` for the content of all your tabs.

Comment: That's a nice elegant solution, thanks. However I'll go with B. Ordway's answer since it's an FXML solution.